# Laravel Database storing only value not array

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

```
$visitorphonenumber=DB::select('select phonenumber from visitortable where email=?',[Auth::user()->email]);

$booking=new bookingmodel();
$booking->visitorphonenumber=$visitorphonenumber;
```

This stores the value like `[{"phonenumber":"9874589608"}]` in database but I want to store only the `9874589608`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
$visitorphonenumber=DB::select('select phonenumber from visitortable where email=?',[Auth::user()->email]);

$singlePhoneNumber=$visitorphonenumber->first();
```

Comment: [{"phonenumber":"9874589608"}]   is actually printed for my code ..
when i use first it store {"phonenumber":"9874589608"} that is without box braces

Comment: Yes now its solved.when we use get function we cant access dataelements if we access and store it it will store as i described.when we use first() function we are able to access the data elements.

Answer (score 2):

I will add some sugar to above answer, use like

```
$visitorphonenumber->first()->phonenumber;
```